# Allow only one xml root element when using two schemas

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I have 2 schemas. 
First:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="ns1"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

<element name="A" type="string"/>

</schema>
```

Second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="ns2"
        xmlns:ns1="ns1"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

<element name="B">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="ns1:A"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>

</schema>
```

So in instance xml I can use 2 root elements.
Example 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A xmlns="ns1">sdfdfd</A>
```

Example 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<B xmlns="ns2"><A xmlns="ns1">sdfdfd</A></B>
```

How to allow only example 2?

Comment: Why would you want to not allow example 1?

Comment: This is because I need schema to validate xml with digital signature. So I always need `A` as root element. Of course I can validate it without schema, but I wonder if I can do it during schema validation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the API of your schema validator.

In general if an element is valid against a schema, then every child of that element is also valid: therefore, if your second instance is valid, your first one is too, since XSD validates elements rather than documents.

However, a schema validator may allow you to specify the root node for validation. For example if you use Saxon as your schema validator, then from the command line you can specify

-top:{ns2}B

See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/schema-processing/commandline.xml

Comment: Is there analog instruction in C#, .Net for class XmlReader?